# Working Fine In Java Mode, Not So In Javascript (Also Trouble With Algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, processing

I'm currently teaching myself game programming and remaking some of the classic games to learn the different tricks and stuff(as suggested a [fine article](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/your-first-step-to-game-development-starts-here-r2976) on [gamedev.net](http://www.gamedev.net)).

I successfully coded PONG and now working on Snake(I assume that's what it meant by Worm). Now I figured out a lot of the stuff, except for two things I can't wrap my mind around.

My algorithm is simple enough: The player controls the head and the body follows. The head has it's own class and from there each segment is controlled as a separate object. The segments each control their own movement defined by a velocity vector. The first segment is independent from the array that controls the rest of the segments. So the head just sends orders to the first segment and the first segment transmits it to the rest of the segments.

The system is based on BendinPoints. Basically each segment has a variable for storing a BendingPoint coordinate and the velocity vector to take on when reaching that BendingPoint. A flag tells it whether it currently posses a BendingPoint or  is free to accept a new coordinate.

So the head, when it turns, transmits that location *where* it turned and the direction(velocity vector) in which it turned. The first segment passes it on the second, the second passes it on to the third and so on. Each segment only passes an order to the next if it has one to pass. Each segment only receives new orders once the old one has been completed.

Now my problem is two-fold. One: this works fine in Java mode but not working in Javascript mode and I can't figure out why. And Two: Sometimes, when I'm changing direction too rapidly, the rest of the body apart from the head and first segment seem to lose track and wander off.

I hope the code comments will explain the rest. Forgive my newbishness.

```
String MODE;

Menu menu;
String[] menuItems={"START","INSTRUCTIONS","CREDITS","EXIT"};

/*@ pjs font="data/waved.ttf" */
/*@ pjs font="data/sixty.ttf" */
PFont sMenu=createFont("waved",72);
PFont sItem=createFont("sixty",35);

String gOverText="GAME OVER";
String hScoreText="Your score is: ";

String iControl="W,A,S,D turns the Snake in the respective direction.";
String iScore="Each Food increases Score by 1 and a segement is added.";
String iScore2="After every 10 points, number of segments added per Food increases by 1.";

String cBy="coded By";
String cName="Le Shaun";

MenuItem back;

Snake snk;
Food fd;

int hScore;
int dF;

float sWidth=800;
float sHeight=600;

PVector sLoc=new PVector(sWidth/2,sHeight/2);
PVector sVel=new PVector(0,-1);
float sRad=10;
color sCol=#9D6C0A;

PVector fLoc=new PVector(450,300);
float fRad=10;
color fCol=#FCF18C;

void setup(){
  size(int(sWidth),int(sHeight));
  snk=new Snake(sLoc,sVel,sRad,sCol);
  fd=new Food(fLoc,fRad,fCol);
  frameRate(60);

  hScore=0;
  dF=1;

  menu=new Menu("SNAKE",menuItems,sMenu,sItem,color(#9D6C0A),color(#8CC610),color(#EDE724),color(#674707),color(255,0));

  MODE="NIL";

  back=new MenuItem("BACK",sItem,width/2,height/1.5,height/25,color(#8CC610),color(#EDE724),color(#674707),color(255,0));    //Common back button for some of the screens.
}

//Current screen is controlled by MODES. Each MODE defines which parts of the game will run, whether it be individual screens or the main gameplay itself.

void draw(){
  background(#EDB824);

  if(MODE.equals("NIL")){
    menu.render();
    MODE=menu.whichItem();
  }
  else if(MODE.equals("START")){  
    fd.render();
    if(fd.isEaten(snk)){
      for(int i=1;i<=dF;i++){
      snk.sInc();
      }
      hScore++;
    }

    snk.render();
    snk.update();
    if(snk.isDead()){
     MODE="GAMEOVER";
     sLoc=new PVector(width/2,height/2);
     fLoc=new PVector(width/2+100,height/2+100);
     sVel=new PVector(+1,0);
     snk=new Snake(sLoc,sVel,sRad,sCol);
    }

    dF=int(hScore/10)+1;

    textFont(sItem);
    textSize(height/25);
    text(str(hScore),width-textWidth(str(hScore))*3,height-height/25);
  }
  else if(MODE.equals("GAMEOVER")){
    stroke(0);
    fill(#9D6C0A);
    textFont(sMenu);
    textSize(72);
    text(gOverText,width/2-textWidth(gOverText)/2,height/3);
    text(hScoreText+hScore,width/2-textWidth(gOverText)/2,height/2);

    back.render();
    back.update();
    if(back.getClicked()){
      back.unClick();
      MODE="NIL";
      hScore=0;
      frameRate(60);
    }
  }
  else if(MODE.equals("INSTRUCTIONS")){
    stroke(0);
    fill(#9D6C0A);
    textFont(sMenu);
    textSize(72);
    text("INSTRUCTIONS",width/2-textWidth("INSTRUCTIONS")/2,height/3);

    textFont(sItem);
    textSize(20);
    text(iControl,width/2-textWidth(iControl)/2,height/2);
    text(iScore,width/2-textWidth(iScore)/2,height/2+35);
    text(iScore2,width/2-textWidth(iScore2)/2,height/2+70);

    back.render();
    back.update();
    if(back.getClicked()){
      back.unClick();
      MODE="NIL";
    }
  }
  else if(MODE.equals("CREDITS")){
    stroke(0);
    fill(#9D6C0A);
    textFont(sItem);

    textSize(35);
    text(cBy,width/2-textWidth(cBy)/2,height/2);

    textSize(45);
    text(cName,width/2-textWidth(cName)/2,height/1.7);

    back.render();
    back.update();
    if(back.getClicked()){
      back.unClick();
      MODE="NIL";
    }
  }


  //println(MODE);
}

void keyReleased(){
  if(MODE.equals("START")){
    String temp="";
    temp+=key;
    temp=temp.toUpperCase();
    snk.changeDir(temp);

    if(key=='v' || key=='V'){
      frameRate(60);
    }
  }
}

void keyPressed(){
    if(MODE.equals("START")){
    if(key=='v' || key=='V'){
      frameRate(180);
    }
  }
}

void mouseClicked(){
  if(MODE.equals("NIL")){
    menu.passTo(mouseX,mouseY);
  }
  if(MODE.equals("GAMEOVER") || MODE.equals("INSTRUCTIONS") || MODE.equals("CREDITS")){
    back.mClicked(mouseX,mouseY);
  }
}


//Menu class uses the objects from the MenuItem and forms a menu with a title and a list of MenuItem objects.

/*
  Constructor: Str-MenuTitle, Str[]-MenuItems, PF-MenuFont, PF-MenuItemFont, c-TitleColor, c-ItemTextColor, c-ItemBackColor, c-ItemHoverTextColor, c-ItemHoverBackColor.

  Methods:
      void render() - Renders the MenuTitle and the MenuItems.
      void passTo(float,float) - Passes the mouse coords to each MenuItem to check whether it has been clicked.
      void passTo(int) - Resets the clickState of the specified MenuItem by calling the unClick() method on that MenuItem.
      String whichItem() - Checks all the MenuItems for a their clickState and returns the one that's been clicked.
*/

class Menu{
  String titleT;

  PFont titleF;
  PFont menuItem;

  color titleC;

  float spacer;    //This is used to define the space between successive MenuItem objects.
  float iniY=height/2.5;

  MenuItem[] menuItems;

  Menu(String titleT,String[] menuItemsNames,PFont titleF,PFont menuItemF,color titleC,color menuItemC,color menuBackC,color itemHoverC,color backHoverC){
    this.titleT=titleT;
    this.titleF=titleF;
    this.titleC=titleC;

    menuItems=new MenuItem[menuItemsNames.length];  //Initializes the MenuItem objects depending on the array passed to it. This makes the menu system very flexible.
    spacer=48;
    for(int i=0;i<menuItemsNames.length;i++){      
      menuItems[i]=new MenuItem(menuItemsNames[i],menuItemF,width/2,iniY+(spacer*i),height/25,menuItemC,menuBackC,itemHoverC,backHoverC);
    }
  }

  void render(){  //Renders the menu.
    textFont(titleF);
    textSize(92);
    fill(titleC);
    text(titleT,width/2-(textWidth(titleT)/2),height/3.8);

    for(int i=0;i<menuItems.length;i++){
      menuItems[i].update();
      menuItems[i].render();
    }
  }

  void passTo(float mX,float mY){    //This accepts the X,Y mouse coords when the mouse is clicked and passes it to the relevant MenuItem object to check if the click occurs on that object.
    for(int i=0;i<menuItems.length;i++){
      menuItems[i].mClicked(mX,mY);
    }
  }

  /*void passTo(int item){  //This accepts an ineteger value and resets that particular menu item's click state.
    menuItems[item].unClick();
  }*/

  String whichItem(){  //Checks each time if the clickState of any MenuItem object is true. If it is, returns the array position of the relevant object.
    for(int i=0;i<menuItems.length;i++){
      if(menuItems[i].getClicked()){
        menuItems[i].unClick();
        return menuItems[i].menuItem;
      }
    }
    return "NIL";
  }
}


//MenuItem holds the attributes and methods relating to each single item on the menu. Thus each item is treated as a separate object.
//Each MenuItem object comprises mainly of a foreground text and a background object. 



class MenuItem{

  String menuItem;
  PFont menuFont;
  float itemX;
  float itemY;
  float itemSize;
  color itemColor;
  color backColor;
  color pressedColor;
  color pressedBack;

  color presentItem;
  color presentBack;

  float textWidth;

  boolean clickState=false;  //This vairable is used to check the clickState of the menu item. If the mouse is clicked over the menu item, this variable becomes true.

  MenuItem(String menuItem,PFont menuFont,float itemX,float itemY,float itemSize,color itemColor,color backColor,color pressedColor,color pressedBack){
    this.menuItem=menuItem;
    this.menuFont=menuFont;
    this.itemX=itemX;
    this.itemY=itemY;
    this.itemSize=itemSize;
    this.itemColor=itemColor;
    this.backColor=backColor;
    this.pressedColor=pressedColor;
    this.pressedBack=pressedBack;
  }

  void render(){    //Handles the rendering for individual menu objects.
    textFont(menuFont);
    textSize(itemSize);
    textWidth=textWidth(menuItem);

    stroke(0);
    fill(presentBack);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(itemX,itemY,textWidth*1.3,itemSize*1.4,50);

    fill(presentItem);
    text(menuItem,itemX-textWidth/2,itemY+itemSize*.3);
  }

  void update(){             //Constatnly checks for the state of the object. If the mouse is over it a certain style is show and otherwise another style is shown.
    if(mouseX<(itemX+(textWidth*1.3)/2) && mouseX>(itemX-(textWidth*1.3)/2) && mouseY<(itemY+(itemSize*1.4)/2) && mouseY>(itemY-(itemSize*1.4)/2)){
     presentItem=pressedColor;
     presentBack=pressedBack;
     noStroke();
    }
    else{
     presentItem=itemColor;
     presentBack=backColor;
    }
  }

  boolean getClicked(){    //Returns the clickState of the object.
    return clickState;
  }

  void unClick(){      //Resets the click state after having been clicked once.
    clickState=false;
  }

  void mClicked(float mX,float mY){  //Changes the clickState of the object depending on the position of the mouse as inputs.
    if(mX<(itemX+(textWidth*1.3)/2) && mX>(itemX-(textWidth*1.3)/2) && mY<(itemY+(itemSize*1.4)/2) && mY>(itemY-(itemSize*1.4)/2)){
      clickState=true;
      println(menuItem);
    }
  }
}



/*
  All control comes from the Snake's head. The head works directly with the first segment(SnakeBits object) and the first segement works with the rest of the body.
  Each time a food is consumed, a new segment is created, it's position and velocity calculated as per the position of the last segment.
  A loop checks whether each segment is open to receiving a new set of orders(BendingPoint and the velocity for that point), and passes on if so.

*/

class Snake{  //Controls the snake's head as well as the segment objects.  

  PVector sLoc;  //Location and Velocity.
  PVector sVel;

  float sRad;  //Radius and Color
  float shRad;    
  color sCol;

  float baseVel;  //The base velocity of the snake.

  SnakeBits[] sBits={};  //Array of SnakeBits objects that forms the segments.

  PVector hold;

  Snake(PVector sLoc,PVector sVel,float sRad,color sCol){
    this.sLoc=sLoc;
    this.sVel=sVel;
    this.sRad=sRad;
    this.shRad=sRad*1.;
    this.sCol=sCol;
    this.baseVel=abs(sVel.x>0 ? sVel.x : sVel.y);  //The snake is initially given a vector in one of the cardinal directions. Whatever the value of velocity is in either direction is stored.

    hold=PVector.mult(sVel,shRad+sRad);
    hold=PVector.sub(sLoc,hold);
    sBits=(SnakeBits[])append(sBits,new SnakeBits(hold,sVel,sRad,sCol));
  }

  void update(){  //Updates the movement of the head as well as the segments.
    updateBP();

    sLoc.add(sVel);
    for(int i=0;i<sBits.length;i++){
      sBits[i].update();
    }    
  }

  void render(){  //The display.
    stroke(0);
    fill(sCol);
    ellipse(sLoc.x,sLoc.y,shRad*2.2,shRad*2.2);

    for(int i=0;i<sBits.length;i++){
      sBits[i].render();
    }
  }

  void sInc(){  //Gets called each time a food item is eaten, and increases the size of the snake by adding segments based on the velocity vector of the last segment.
    int lastInd=sBits.length-1;
    hold=PVector.mult(sBits[lastInd].sbVel,sRad*2);
    hold=PVector.sub(sBits[lastInd].sbLoc,hold);
    PVector appVel=new PVector(sBits[lastInd].sbVel.x,sBits[lastInd].sbVel.y);
    SnakeBits appBits=new SnakeBits(hold,appVel,sRad,sCol);
    sBits=(SnakeBits[])append(sBits,appBits);
  }

  void changeDir(String dir){  //Gets called when a directional button is pressed. 
    PVector chng=new PVector(0,0);  //Direction change can only occur perpendicular to the current direction. Uses baseVel to set the new direction.
    if(!sBits[0].hasBP){
      if(degrees(sVel.heading())==0 || degrees(sVel.heading())==180){
        if(dir.equals("W")){
          chng=new PVector(0,-baseVel);
          sVel=chng;
          updateFBP();
        }
        else if(dir.equals("S")){
          chng=new PVector(0,baseVel);
          sVel=chng;
          updateFBP();
        }
      }
      else if(degrees(sVel.heading())==90 || degrees(sVel.heading())==-90){
        if(dir.equals("D")){
          chng=new PVector(baseVel,0);
          sVel=chng;
          updateFBP();
        }
        else if(dir.equals("A")){
          chng=new PVector(-baseVel,0);
          sVel=chng;
          updateFBP();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  boolean isDead(){  //Checks for collision against the wall or it's own tail.
    if((sLoc.x-shRad)<0 || (sLoc.x+shRad)>width || (sLoc.y-shRad)<0 || (sLoc.y+shRad)>height){
       println("WALL");
      return true;
    }
    PVector temp;
    for(int i=0;i<sBits.length;i++){ 
      if(dist(sLoc.x,sLoc.y,sBits[i].sbLoc.x,sBits[i].sbLoc.y)<(shRad+sRad-sRad*.6)){
        println("TAIL");
        println(sLoc.x+" "+sLoc.y+" "+sBits[i].sbLoc.x+" "+sBits[i].sbLoc.y+" "+dist(sLoc.x,sLoc.y,sBits[i].sbLoc.x,sBits[i].sbLoc.y)+" "+(shRad+sRad-sRad*.6));
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
 }

 void updateFBP(){     //Updates the first segment's BendingPoint.
      sBits[0].takeNewBP(sLoc,sVel);
      sBits[0].hasNewBP(true);  
  }

 void updateBP(){  //Updates the rest of the segments as per the system of receiving new orders once the current orders have been executed.
   for(int i=0;i<sBits.length-1;i++){
     if(sBits[i].hasBP && !sBits[i+1].hasBP){
       sBits[i+1].takeNewBP(sBits[i].newBP,sBits[i].newVel);
       sBits[i+1].hasNewBP(true);
     }
   }
 }


}


/*
  Each SnakeBit has it's independent movement system. It holds a BendPoint(newBP) variable, a New BP Velocity(newVel) variable and a flag(hasBP) to show whether it has a new Bend Point.
  When the SnakeBit already has a BP, it will wait till it reaches that BP and then take on the velocity from newVel. It's flag will be set to false.
  In this state it will be open to receiving a new set of orders: a new BP and the velocity to take on for that BP. Thus new BP's are not taken on till the previous BP has been cleared.
*/

class SnakeBits{  //The individual bits of the snake that make up its body.

  boolean hasBP;

  PVector sbLoc;  //Location and Velocity vectors.
  PVector sbVel;

  float sbRad;  //Radius and color of the segment.
  color sbCol;

  PVector newBP;  //This works with the changeDir() method. It holds the position at which the direction will be changed.
  PVector newVel;  //Stores the new Velocity vector that will be applied when the above position is reached.

  SnakeBits(PVector sbLoc,PVector sbVel,float sbRad,color sbCol){
    this.sbLoc=sbLoc;
    this.sbVel=sbVel;
    this.sbRad=sbRad;
    this.sbCol=sbCol;
    newVel=new PVector(sbVel.x,sbVel.y);
    newBP=new PVector(width*2,height*2);  //Initialized it as such to avoid problems during first run.
    hasBP=false;
  }

  void render(){
    stroke(0);
    fill(sbCol);
    ellipse(sbLoc.x,sbLoc.y,sbRad*2,sbRad*2);
  }

  void update(){
    sbLoc.add(sbVel);  //Both updates the Location and checks if it's time to change direction.
    changeDir(); 
  }

  void changeDir(){
    if(sbLoc.x==newBP.x && sbLoc.y==newBP.y && hasBP){  //As soon as the segment reaches the Location where a change in dir is needed, the Velocity is changed over to the new velocity vector.
      println("FTRUE");
      hasNewBP(false);
      sbVel.x=newVel.x;  sbVel.y=newVel.y;
      newBP=new PVector(width*2,height*2);
    }

  }

  void takeNewBP(PVector pos,PVector vel){  //Called externally by the Snake class. Takes where last segment changed direction and stores that location as well as the new velocity vector.
    newBP.x=pos.x;  newBP.y=pos.y;
    newVel.x=vel.x; newVel.y=vel.y; 
  }

  void hasNewBP(boolean dat){  //Updates the hasBP state by accepting a boolean and assigning it to hasBP.
    hasBP=dat;
  }
}


class Food{

  PVector fLoc;

  float fRad;
  color fCol;

  Food(PVector fLoc,float fRad,color fCol){
    this.fLoc=fLoc;
    this.fRad=fRad;
    this.fCol=fCol;
  }

  void render(){
    stroke(0);
    fill(fCol);
    ellipse(fLoc.x,fLoc.y,fRad*2,fRad*2);
  }

  boolean isEaten(Snake sn){
    PVector temp;
    temp=PVector.sub(fLoc,sn.sLoc);
    if(temp.mag()<(sn.shRad+fRad)){
      reset(sn);
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  void reset(Snake sn){
    boolean set=false;
    PVector tmp=new PVector();
    while(!set){
      tmp=new PVector(random(fRad,width-fRad),random(fRad,height-fRad));
      set=true;
      for(int i=0;i<sn.sBits.length;i++){
        if(dist(tmp.x,tmp.y,sn.sBits[i].sbLoc.x,sn.sBits[i].sbLoc.y)<(fRad+sn.sRad) || dist(tmp.x,tmp.y,sn.sLoc.x,sn.sLoc.y)<(fRad+sn.shRad)){
          set=false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    fLoc=tmp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is part 2 what happens in part 1? If not, be more clear than "it doesn't work"

Comment: No, the two problems are completely different. The code actually runs when I'm running it in Java mode, but I'm facing the second problem and only when I change direction too rapidly. But in Javascript mode the menu itself refuses to show up.

Comment: What do you mean by "Java mode" and "JavaScript mode"? Java and JavaScript are completely different programming languages.

Comment: Forgive me but I clearly tagged this question as a Processing question. I'm very much aware that Java and Javascript are two different languages, but if you don't know what I mean by those respective modes then you are not familiar with processing and therefore unsuited to help me. This might enlighten you: http://www.processing.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript mode seems to have a problem with textWidth(); To get over it you can change textWidth=textWidth(menuItem); in MenuItem.render() to textWidth=200; or find a working equivalent.

By the way, I noticed that when I run it in Javascript, it wouldn't take its full size and your size(); command is the culprit. It seems to require numbers instead of variables to function properly (setting it to size(800,600); worked)

Your other problem seems to stem from the fact that you change things when you press a button but you dont apply the change until the draw() function. Unfortunately I can't pinpoint it in your code by making small changes, which makes me believe that you need to refactor your turning system in a different fashion. My suggestion is to decouple where everyone has to go from where the previous one goes, opting instead to store the positions and directions he has to go in an ArrayList, which will grow essentially with each turn. Then, each bit of the snake has to go through its own ArrayList of directions and positions without regarding the momentary changes of its previous one. When it does reach one of those positions just turn it in the proper direction, delete the reached direction and position and start heading for the next one. The ArrayList essentially functions like a queue, where you add to the end but remove from the beginning.

Maybe it makes sense to post the second part of your question to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Works like a charm! :D I used a LinkedList instead of an ArrayList but the algorithm remained the same and it works beautifully. Thank you.